# Unwrap selected area, keep the borders

Tags: uv, workflow, uv-image-editor

I had to fix the topology on some parts of an existing model. The model is unwrapped, rigged, and textured. Now the fixed parts have stretched UVs that do not fit the texture. I want to unwrap those new parts but keep their borders on UV, so they can perfectly fit into the existing UV island. I can not find any available option that would allow me to do it in Blender -_- Please, help

Comment: select the fixed faces, and hit unwrap again and then you have to adjust the UV verts as you like it. There might be an easier solution - i only know that one.

Comment: You just need to pin (P) the uv faces that you want to keep as they are and unwrap again selecting the new area too. But try to make a backup before you make any changes in order for you to test this.

Comment: Both solutions do not work: if you pin the border, those pinned vertices stay in place, but the active polygons get separated into a new UV island instead of unwrapping inside the borders.

Comment: You need to pin your whole original model not the new faces nor the borders only, all the original model and then select All and unwrap

Comment: Hmmm I am confused. If I pin all then nothing changes when I unwrap. Also I must not change any other area but the one that was fixed.